# Procedure or function ' ' expects parameter ' ' which is not supplied

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've annoyingly got what appears to be a very 'popular' error. However, in my case I'm supplying the expected parameter and it definitely has a value, so I'm stumped. Here's my code:

```
public static DataTable MyDataTable(string pd, bool showAll)
{
    DataTable results = new DataTable("PD results");

    string Conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Conn))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.MyProcedure", connection);

        SqlParameter pdParam = new SqlParameter("@i_user", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        pdParam.Value = pd;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(pdParam);

        if (showAll) 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i_ShowALL", (int)1);
        else 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i_ShowALL", (int)0);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        try
        {
            da.Fill(results);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }
     }

     return results;
}
```

I've stepped through the code and the error occurs with parameter `@i_user`. However, when I'm adding the parameter it has a value and I confirmed this when looking at the SqlDataAdapter > SelectCommand >Parameters > Non-Public members > items > [0] {@i_user} > base > value.

Despite having the parameter supplied with a `varchar` value I get the error

> Procedure or function 'dbo.MyProcedure' expects parameter '@i_user' which is not supplied

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Suggestion: add `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`

Comment: As Dmity says, you are not telling the `SqlCommand` that you are running a stored procedure so it is interpretting you command as a simple sql string, which does not contain any params.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko - that solved the problem. I'd completely forgotten to add that in. Stupid mistake. If you add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of the error is that `SqlCommand` class expects a *plain text SQL*.
When assigning *stored procedure name* (`"dbo.MyProcedure"` in your case) add

```
  ... 
  // Do not forget to Dispose IDisposable instances
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.MyProcedure", connection)) {
    // cmd.CommandText is a stored procedure name, not a plain text SQL 
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     ...
  }
```